# How to load html file to android app?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm new to android development and I'm trying to figure out how to load an HTML file that I have which contains a video. Everytime I run my app on my mobile it crashes.

This is my code which is found in the onCreate main class.

```
WebView wv = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.video);
WebSettings wbset=wv.getSettings();
wbset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebClientClass());
wv.loadUrl("file:///assets/video.html");
```

I have the video in the **assets** folder. This is my manifest xml class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.video"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And the **activity** is right here.

```
<pre lang="text">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.video.MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use#**

> wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/video.html");

**Instead#**

> wv.loadUrl("file:///assets/video.html");

For further detail refer [Printing HTML Documents.](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the path of the asset folder. You can get the path of Asset folder using this : wv.loadUrl(context.getAssets().open("video.html")).

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of you use :-

wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/video.html");

Comment: Please provide sort of Description

Comment: instead of this wv.loadUrl("file:///assets/video.html");  use i posted code to load html from assets. i solved by it

Comment: let me try all the solutions